# iOS5 delete tableView section animation

Tags: uitableview, animation, ios5

I have a tableView with a few sections. When I remove all rows from a section, I also remove the section with the UITableViewRowAnimationTop animation (so it slides up). When running the app on an iOS 4 device, the deleteSections: withRowAnimations: method correctly makes the section slide up and disappear behind whatever is above it. However on iOS 5, the section slides up but stays infront of whatever is above it, then disappears once it's finished sliding. What could be wrong?

FYI: I'm using iOS5 but have changed the iOS deployment target to iOS 4.0, so my app will run on all iOS version from 4 upward, and have changed the architecture to armv6 armv7

EDIT: For testing, I created an empty project with just a UITableViewController, which had a couple of sections with a couple of rows in each, nothing fancy. Got the same behaviour, so although I'm really hesitant to do this (because it's almost never the case), I'm going to go out on a limb and say this is a bug in iOS5?

Comment: Dunno whether this has anything to do with your problem, but from the [iOS 5 Release Notes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html)  Returning nil from the tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method (or its footer equivalent) is no longer sufficient to hide a header. You must override tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: and return 0.0 to hide a header.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar problem.  Popping a view controller where the animation is supposed to slide the prior view in from the left (works fine on iOS 4).  But on iOS 5 the bulk of the page appears immediately while only the bottom tab bar slides in from the left.  Have single-stepped through the code on both versions and it appears to be taking the same path right up to the `popViewControllerAnimated` call.

Unfortunately this is a very complex app (unnecessarily complex, but that's another story) where most of the screens are dynamic, so it's hard to simplify down to a test case.  No obvious solution so far.